# Spring and Angular JS HTML5 mode with abstract routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, html, angular-ui-router

I have a project Using Spring and Angular JS. 
When I attempt to remove the ungly "/#/", I followed the following tutorial:

[Configuring HTML 5 mode](https://jhipster.github.io/v2-documentation/tips/010_tip_configuring_html_5_mode.html)

in my index html file:

```
<base href="/">
```

in my AngularJS config:

```
app.config(
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        .state('business', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "business/businessView"
        })

        .state('business.intro1', {
            url: "/intro1",
            templateUrl: "business/page-1",
        })

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true)};
    }
);
```

So In order to support resource, I added following JAVA code to my spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
public String redirect() {
    return "forward:/";
}

@RequestMapping("/business/**")
public String returnBusinessHtml() {
    String uri = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
    return  uri;
}
```

and successfully avoided 404 issue when directly access URL.

---

Everything is looking good for now, however, when I add a URL to the abstract controller of angularJS:

```
.state('business', {
    abstract: true,
    url: "/business",
    templateUrl: "business/businessView"
})
```

the 404 issue came out again when I tried to access `localhost:8080/business/intro1`.

If I try other page like `localhost:8080/businessLanding`, It's OK.

Maybe the issue came out from `@RequestMapping(value = "/{[path:[^\\.]*}")` this regular expression? Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, I just modified it to the original solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
public String redirect() {
    return "forward:/";
}
```

and everything is done!